# How to get values of all editTexts in layout using Xamarin.android C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

As I wrote in the title, I want to get values in all editTexts in a layout and put it in variable as summation using Xamarin.android, I tried this code but I got nothing

```
var viewGroup = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.myLayout);
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var childView = viewGroup.GetChildAt(i);
            if (childView is EditText)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((EditText)childView).Text))
                    sum += Convert.ToInt32(((EditText)childView).Text);
            }
```

how can I do that please..

Answer (score 0):

What is the error code? Did u try to debug it? This line might be the reason.

```
sum += Convert.ToInt32(((EditText)childView).Text);
```

Comment: there is no error in code, but I get nothing after I excute it

Comment: viewGroup.ChildCount might be 0, all strings may be empty, all childs might sth other than EditText

Comment: I check it and it's actually 0, how can I correct it?

Comment: maybe u are fetching the wrong layout or maybe EditText s are children of sth else

Comment: I've more than 10 EditTexts and it's have a value but no result is appear to me